# How to save the fusion chart (in a webpage) as an image on client's machine.?

Tags: javascript, image, browser, graph, fusioncharts

> **I have an ASP.NET web application. One of the ASCX control in my app has
>   fusion charts displayed in a client
>   side Div tag. I want to provide an
>   option for my clients to download the
>   fusion chart onto their local
>   machine.**

I refered this link http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/ECPureJS.html

It says enabling "exportEnabled" property will provide an option for download button.
I am not using "Javascript charts", instead I am using **Fusion charts free**.
I have  tag in my XML file which I give as input to Fusion charts(). And I added exportEnabled='1' to my  tag of the XML. 
But I didnt get any download button. Can anyone kindly let me know if there is any workaround to download the fusion charts onto client's machine from the webpage. I am using FUSION CHARTS FREE.

PLz help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FusionCharts Free does not support the Export functionality.

Please note that since FusionCharts v3.0.7, you could export your charts as images.
FusionCharts v3.1 allows to export as PDFs as well, and also lets you choose whether to export the charts at client-side or server-side.

For client-side-export, Flash Player 10 is required.

Please refer to the following link to view the FusionCharts export demo.
http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/ExportChart/Contents/client_export.html

The above link displays 3 kind of Export feature supported by FusionCharts.

1. Client side export: Export charts as images (JPEG, PNG) or PDFs at client-side
2. Server side export: Exports charts as images
   a) Can return the image as download to the browser
   b) Save it to the server disk
3. Batch Export: Exporting multiple charts on a page by calling a JavaScript API.

Comment: The link you provided shows the demo. It would be of great help if you can provide the technical details to achieve this. Is it enough to just include the exportEnabled property in my <graph> tag. Or what steps should I follow to achieve this. Can you plz help with some details regarding this or any links. :)

Comment: Please note that Export functionality is not supported by FusionCharts Free. Hence the attribute "exportEnabled" in the <graph> tag is also invalid in this case.

Comment: The Export process works for FusionCharts v3 (http://www.fusioncharts.com/), which is an altogether different product than FusionCharts Free and a commercial product as well. The steps that you have followed in this case is completely valid for FusionCharts v3 Export process.

Comment: I am totally new to fusion charts coding. Pardon me if I sound silly. Can you guide me with the steps to be followed for using the Fusion charts V3.

Comment: I mean how to get access of Fusion charts V3 and than after downloading V3 is it just enough if I include exportEnabled='1' in my <graph> tag of the XML OR Should I use any specific API available in Fusion charts V3 for that.

Comment: Please try downloading the latest Evaluation version of FusionCharts, i.e FusionCharts v3.2.1 with the help of the following link: http://www.fusioncharts.com/download/

Comment: Please try exporting the charts exactly the way you are currently doing. Please refer to the following links for the export process in FusionCharts v3. Ref.- http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/?ECProcess.html, http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/?ECXML.html  In case you face any issues, I am there to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not export FusionCharts FREE charts to image and to be downloaded on client's machine.

You need to use [FusionCharts v3](http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/?ECOverview.html) to make use of this feature.